# Detect Viewport and Redirect To Different Homepage

Tags: javascript, html, browser, client-side, viewport

I want to redirect the homepage to a different view if the initial viewport is a certain dimension.  I was thinking about doing this with javascript and doing a redirect within the head tag.  Is this the best possible way or can I detect anything on the server side first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t detect viewport size on the server, you need to do it client side.

A client-side redirect might not be your best solution either since it is obstructive and bad for search engines. Instead you can use media queries to apply different stylesheets (or cascades) targeting different ranges of screen resolutions without any server-side interaction.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using different stylesheets better than my suggestion below of serving different content via AJAX.

Comment: This is responsive web design in a nut shell.

Comment: The homepage contains alot of content and an ajax call might not be the best approach.  I do like the different style sheets, which I would do anyway, but these computers are in school labs and are a certain dimension so SEO shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Can you explain the media queries?  Not sure I follow without an example.

Comment: There are tons of articles that can explain the fundamental principles much better than me, here is a descent start: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the viewport / browser size cannot be done server side. You could do it with Javascript. Note that you do not have to redirect, you could load alternative content based on viewport size with AJAX.